# values are not being inserted into resultset after executing preparedstatement in executeQuery()

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

i have written the following  code

```
PrepareStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from studentdetails where sname=?");
String snm=jTextField10.getText();
ps.setString(1,snm);
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
```

the problem i'm facing is that the result set is empty, i have checked with the database and the values i gave in the gui for search is valid. please tell me what migt be the problem.

Comment: Did you mean `stmt.setString(1,snm);`?

Comment: are you certain that there is a value in jTextField10.getText(); ??

Comment: Did you do rs.first and/or rs.next?

Comment: And following on from Pradeep, are you sure there's no leading or trailing white space in the text field value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from studentdetails where sname=?");
String snm=jTextField10.getText();
stmt.setString(1,snm);
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
```

Try the above code. Everything in your code is fine, only problem is with the 'PreparedStatement instance', and the 'PrepareStatement'. It is 'PreparedStatement', you have missed the 'd' there. You have declared an instance of PreparedStatement called 'stmt' but you have set the value using another called 'ps'.

Small Note:

I don't like the name you have given to the JTextField. in OOP, it is recommended to give a meaningful names to instances, Objects, Methods, Variables etc

Answer (score 0):

Write this one This might help you.

```
PrepareStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from studentdetails where sname=?");
String snm=jTextField10.getText();
stmt.setString(1,snm);
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
```